# AngularJS- Text is not binding with Jquery time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this simple piece of Angular Code which displays the selected time.
But the date selected is not binding with the text area.
As an alternative I used HTML5 datetime-local input which worked properly.
It's the jQuery timepicker which is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="angularjs">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="text" id="dates" ng-model="tdata">
        <text>{{tdata}}</text>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $("#dates").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
})
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Never ever use jquery with angular. You should use Angular UI for this: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the model is not being updated when you change the value of the field (however, if you type into the field then it will update accordingly). The only reason I can think of this is that the way datepicker works is that it does not send out an event when the field is changed (so it just updates the value of the field and no event is fired).

In order to fix this you can add `onSelect` to the datepicker and manually update the tdata field like so...

```js
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {

 $scope.tdata = '';
    
 $("#dates").datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, 
        onSelect: function(data) {
         $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.tdata = data;
         });
     }
    });
})
```

Comment: bad idea mix jquery with angular. He should just use some directive that does the job.

Comment: @Fals Yes it is a bad idea but I answered the question he had. I didn't just complain that he shouldn't do it that way.

Comment: why is it a bad idea to use both together?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830498/angular-and-mixing-jquery-ui-why-not gives an okay insight as to why.

Comment: @VinithVenkatesan its like doing anti-pattern in angular..Its not the way angular does..do look at this answer..you should do it using directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808502/how-to-make-a-directive-update-ng-model-on-jquery-on-event

Comment: Oh, got a decent idea why not to use both. If i had made a new directive, the digest cycle problem might not have occurred and it's reusable. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try a directive.  Check out this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/louisnovick/upj137e3/

var datePicker = angular.module('app', []);

```
datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Your Html should be

```
<input type="text" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker />
<br/>
{{ date }}
```